# What is the proper way to concatenate strings with JavaScript (JSX) template literals when one is after comma

Tags: javascript, string, reactjs

I have two strings which I want to concatenate using template literals. Second one is optional and I want to put it after comma (if exist).
I know I can do something like this (but it doesn't look proper to me):

```
<div>
  {a}
  {b ? `, ${b}` : ''}
</div>
```

Comment: I can't think of a more proper way.

Comment: `[a, b].filter(i => i).join(", ")` - if you don't insist about literals

Comment: @Alex Would that be cleaner?

Comment: Yes and no, its relative to what you find to be more readable. And also on whether or not you are planning to add more variables later on

Comment: @Treycos I don't need to add more variables there and I'm looking here for the most proper way to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can incapsulate logic to filter empty and joining into the component member (or util function), i.e.:

```
const concatNotEmptyBy = (separator) 
   => (...args) 
   => args
        .filter(n => n) // filter empty
        .join(separator);
```

and next call it in your component:

```
<div>
  {concatNotEmptyBy(', ')(a, b)}
</div>
```

however, if it's only 1 place and only 2 variables then your original way is totally ok.